# Fineuploader CORS not working in Chrome

Tags: cors, fine-uploader

I have fine uploader working, in a CORS environment. I can show a success response in IE8 + IE9, with the progress bar turning green and the response data as success, along with the script tag appended to the json response and my image is uploading to the server.. all working great.

I'm a little stuck getting the same code to work in modern browsers though. Chrome for instance is returning success true and json block returns the uploaded image (which is uploading correctly to the server), but the response has the script tag and the plugin is showing a false response to the user.. so Im almost there, everything is wokring but the script tag is being added regardless of the browser used.

Now, according to the following page: http://blog.fineuploader.com/2013/01/31/cors-support-in-3-3/, 'An incoming upload request was sent via a form submission inside of a hidden iframe if the request does not have an X-Requested-With header, or if the X-Requested-With header has a value other than `XMLHttpRequest`'. So I am checking in php for the following variable: `echo $_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'];` and its returning as undefined in Chrome.

My complete check is as follows:

```
if ((!isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'])) || (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && $_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'] != "XMLHttpRequest")) {
header("Content-Type: text/html");
    $result['uuid'] = $_REQUEST['qquuid'];
    echo json_encode($result);
    echo "<script src=\"http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']."/frontend/js/iframe.xss.response-3.7.1.js\"></script>";
} else {
    header('Content-Type: text/plain');
    echo json_encode($result);
}
```

So regardless of browser, first if block is failing and Im returning the script response every time.

I can see in my options response headers the 'X-Requested-With' header as allowed. However I don't see this value being passed through with the actual upload request, so obviously it cannot be checked in the if statement. So I can see where my code is failing, I'm just not sure what I need to do to get the header in the second call, do I need to manually add it ?..

Little bit lost and would appreciate any help.
Thanks.

Update
Here is the fineuploader code I am using
[code http://shapevoid.com/code.png](http://shapevoid.com/code.png)

Options request/response
[options http://shapevoid.com/options-request.jpg](http://shapevoid.com/options-request.jpg)

Upload request/response
[upload http://shapevoid.com/upload-request.jpg](http://shapevoid.com/upload-request.jpg)

Comment: Your logic seems correct. Note that, since non-standards headers are sent with all Fine Uploader requests (e.g., X-Requested-With), ALL XHR requests are **preflighted**. This applies to both delete file requests (which are all XHR requests) and upload requests on browsers that support the File API. This means that you will need to handle an OPTIONS request as well. Your responses must include the appropriate Access-Control headers. Are you handling the preflighted OPTIONS request?

Comment: Yes the OPTIONS call is being handled. As I noted above the upload is working always (IE8,9 & Chrome, FF, IE10) and the response from PHP is always success true, I just am having trouble differentiating what type of request it was as the X-Requested-with header is not passed through on a CORS request and therefore am stuck always passing back the script tag block after the json response which is breaking in modern browsers. I have uploaded the test code to the server to test a same domain upload and can confirm the X-Requested-With header IS present when submitting same domain.

Comment: Just to confirm, the X-Requested-With header is only being sent on same domain requests, not on CORS requests.

Comment: Please post your client-side code.

Answer (score 0):

The X-Requested-With header is always sent to traditional endpoints by Fine Uploader with each upload request.  As Mark mentioned, you are not properly handling the OPTIONS/preflight request.  The OPTIONS request will, of course, not contain any non-standard headers.  This request is sent by the browser, not Fine Uploader.  You must acknowledge the OPTIONS request.  If you acknowledge the preflight (via appropriate Access-Control-Allow-* headers in your response) the underlying upload request will be sent, containing the X-Requested-With header.  In the preflight request, the X-Requested-With header will be mentioned in the Access-Control-Request-Headers request header.  I suggest you look at the link I mentioned in my blog post which goes into CORS support in more detail.  (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP/Access_control_CORS).

I can assure you that the X-Requested-With header is present on the underlying request.  If you are not seeing it server-side, then there is some issue with your code.  Have a look at the network tab in Chrome for details.

Comment: Hi have added my code, plus the options and upload requests examples above, hopefully this gives a better idea of whats happening and allows some insights to be gained.

Comment: @JoeShields What version of Fine Uploader are you using, and have you modified any of the uploader code?

Comment: We're using the following version.
<script src="js/jquery.fineuploader-3.7.1.js"></script>

I have re-downloaded the server code as we had made some mods due to our clients req & env. I noticed the filenames have been changed on the server code. 

I didn't see the
js/jquery.fineuploader-3.7.1.js in the new 'master' from github, assuming this is the /js/uploader.js file?

I am testing the updated server files + our mods to see if anything we have done is breaking. We're a paying customer so is it possible to take this offline and share our complete code with you directly?

Thanks

Comment: You must use a combined javascript file.  The files in the source tree/github repo are not meant to be individually imported into your document/page.  I would suggest using the latest version, 3.9.0-3, for starters.  You should have received this via email from us on September 18.